# strange error for string

Tags: c, string, pointers

I have written this easy code

```
     void check(uint16_t *m)
     {            
        while(*m!=0x0D)  {
            if(*m==0x43)  //C 0x43
            {
                ... do something
            }
            *m++;
        } 
     }
```

....
  // in the main

```
      {
         uint16_t buffer[2]; 
         ......
         check(&buffer);
      }
```

Now I have this alert in the function check,

> **note: expected `uint16_t *` but argument is of type `uint16_t (*)[2]`**

I don't understand why the compiler gives me this error.

Comment: @Ehsan I think he means to check against `0x0D` or decimal 14.

Comment: Oh yeah you 're write I really made a big mistake

Comment: But I say if he ain't developing for embedded systems he need not to use hex values instead of `NULL` or `'c'`

Comment: Actually that way your application is more portable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `buffer` is already an array of two `uint16_t`s, and you need to pass a `uint16_t *` to `check()`, then all you need to do is pass the array itself (since it will just decay to a pointer to the first element).

So, change:

```
   check(&buffer);
```

to:

```
   check(buffer);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass address , just pass the `buffer` itself.

```
check(buffer);
```

This will do .

As in function it will decay to pointer to first element of array , therefore, when you pass address of `buffer` it becomes pointer to array that is of type `int16_t (*)[2]` .

Therefore , when you pass `&buffer` which is not expected by your function ,compiler issues error.

Comment: Yeah you should pass buffer instead of &buffer

Comment: coz compiler thinks that you want to pass a two dimensional array

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `buffer` being an array type, `&buffer` is of type as a pointer to an array, like `uint16_t (*)[2]`.

OTOH, your function expects an argument of type pointer to a variable, like `uint16_t *`.

The array name, itself, boils down to the address of the first element thus giving a pointer to a variable only. Remove the `&` from the function call and your compiler will be happy.